# How to write functions for CurrentYear and PreviousYear in scala?

Tags: scala

I have this scenario where I am fetching for CurrentDate. Adding to that I also want to fetch data from CurrentYear and PreviousYear

```scala
def getCurrentDate: String = {
  val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
  cal.add(Calendar.DATE, amount = 0)
  new SimpleDateFormat(pattern = "yyyyMMdd").format(cal.getTime())
}

def getCurrentYear: String = {
  val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
  cal.add(Calendar.DATE, amount = 0)
  new SimpleDateFormat(pattern = "yyyyMMdd").format(cal.getTime())
}
```

I am actually figuring out on how to write this simple function

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to know that the current year depends on your timezone.
So you first need to choose the timezone for which you want to know the year... specially in edge scenarios like new years eve.

That being said, you can do this:

```scala
import java.time._

val yourTZ: ZoneId = ...

def currentDate = Instant.now.atZone(yourTZ).toString.take(10) // because the toString uses ISO formatting

def currentYear = currentDate.take(4)

def previousYear = (currentYear.toInt-1).toString
```